# how do I add a multiple styles to the same :style attribute?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify and I wanted to add multiple styles to the same style attriibute. I have a vuetify breakpoint already inplace and I wanted to add `{backgroundColor:'Color'}` in the same attribute? Putting them side by side doesn't seem to work.

```
<v-container fluid class="menu" :style="$vuetify.breakpoint.xs ? 'width: 13vw;' : 'width: 5vw' 
        **Here's where I want {backgroundColor:Color}**">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles) more inline styles.

```
<v-container
  fluid
  class="menu"
  v-bind:style="{ width: $vuetify.breakpoint.xs? '13vw' : '5vw', 
  backgroundColor: Color }"
>
```